# Selecting list item

Tags: python, list, slice

need help on this

```
Example to select first 5 items from the below list
nums = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
nums[:5]
output = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

If I want my output like below.
Expected output = [10,20,60,70,90]

Please let me know how to achieve this.

I am trying something like this
nums[:1,5:6,8]
nums[0,1,5,6,8]

Comment: Common slice notation does not allow for such complicated logic, you would have to do: `nums[:2] + nums[5:7] + nums[8:]`

Comment: The "duplicate" question is not a duplicate. This question is different - it asks about multi slices which are not mentioned in the dupe

Comment: @Patrick Artner please remove the duplicate tag for this question as i checked the Understanding slice notation question but no where it mentioned about + operater. It is just rhe basic which is not helping. Thanks

Comment: @Jk185 I added the dupe for the concattenating problem as well - you had problems with the slice syntax (_I am trying `nums[:1,5:6,8]`_)  so that one popped out at first.

Comment: Here's another duplicate: [Multiple Slices With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38895781/2745495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could concatenate multiple 3 lists to achieve this, one composed of the first 3 elements, one with elements 60,70 and one with the last element like this:

```
nums = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
print(nums[:2] + nums[5:7] + nums[-1:])

# output [10,20,60,70,90]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I am going to use your answer as it fits well with my issue. I was unaware of the + operator.

Answer (score 1):

One way of indexing using arrays can be done using numpy

`> pip install numpy`

```
import numpy as np

nums = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
nums_np = np.array(nums)
inds = np.array([0,1,5,6,8])
result = nums_np[inds]
print(results)
```

---

Another way:

```
result = np.r_[nums_np[:2], nums_np[5:7], nums_np[8]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer both are working for me and got to know something new